# Error: Command failed: git rev-parse --git-dir after running npm install on main project

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

Clone  git from https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat

npm install

```
E:\2019_PROJECTS\test\react-native-gifted-chat-master\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

This is the base project. Ive downloaded it to look at the different examples. but the project wont install. can anyone please assist? how do you run the examples projects?

Comment: I have a same problem did you get the answer?